# Impute via fill-forward/LOCF a column over a range of sequential rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, time-series, data-warehouse, data-cleaning

When formatting data for time-series analysis, a common need is to impute missing values by filling-forward values over time (also called Last-Observation-Carried-Forward / LOCF ).

While data-analysis environments typically provide that functionality (e.g. Pandas `fillna()` ), for larger data-sets it can be more efficient to compute it in SQL (e.g. utilizing a data-parallel data-warehouse appliance).

For example, consider:

```
    | UNIT | TIME | VALUE |
    |------|------|-------|
    | 1    | 1    | NULL  |
    | 1    | 2    | .5    |
    | 1    | 3    | NULL  |
    | 1    | 4    | NULL  |
    | 1    | 5    | .2    |
    | 1    | 6    | NULL  |
    | 2    | 1    | .6    |
    | 2    | 2    | NULL  |
```

which, after filling-forward the VALUE column over TIME (independently for each UNIT) yields:

```
    | UNIT | TIME | VALUE |
    |------|------|-------|
    | 1    | 1    | NULL  |
    | 1    | 2    | .5    |
    | 1    | 3    | .5    |
    | 1    | 4    | .5    |
    | 1    | 5    | .2    |
    | 1    | 6    | .2    |
    | 2    | 1    | .6    |
    | 2    | 2    | .6    |
```

(Notice the initial NULL for UNIT 1 can't be imputed as there is no prior value)

Time could also be a timestamp or datetime type column.

Comment: On how to linearly interpolate / impute numeric data on PostgreSQL: http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/locf-linear-imputation-postgresql-tutorial/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query structure will achieve fill-forward if using a PostgreSQL flavoured SQL dialect (e.g. Netezza PureData) for a datetime index (assuming past data).  It will also work for multi-column index/keys.

Given the following parameters:

- `<key_cols>` - list of columns uniquely identifying each time-series sample (e.g. `UNIT, TIME` )
- `<impute_col>` - column in which values need to be imputed (e.g. `VALUE` )
- `<impute_over_range_col>` - the sequential range column for the time-series (e.g. `TIME`)

and deriving:

- `<keys_no_range>` - key columns except for `<impute_over_range_col>`

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.<key_cols>, 
                COALESCE(T1.<impute_col>, T2.<impute_col>) AS <impute_col>
FROM table T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT T1.<key_cols>,
                     T1.<impute_col>,
                     LEAD(T1.<impute_over_range_col>,1) 
                         OVER (PARTITION BY T1.<keys_no_range> 
                               ORDER BY T1.<key_cols>)
                         AS NEXT_RANGE
                     FROM table T1
                     WHERE T1.<impute_col> IS NOT NULL
                     ORDER BY T1.<key_cols>
                ) T2
              ON (T1.<impute_over_range_col> BETWEEN T2.<impute_over_range_col> 
                                             AND COALESCE(NEXT_RANGE, CURRENT_DATE)) 
              AND T1.<keys_no_range>[0] = T2.<keys_no_range>[0]
              AND T1.<keys_no_range>[1] = T2.<keys_no_range>[1]
              -- ... for each col in <keys_no_range>
```

Concretely, for the example in the question:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.UNIT, T1.TIME, 
                COALESCE(T1.VALUE, T2.VALUE) AS VALUE
FROM table T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT T1.UNIT, T1.TIME,
                     T1.VALUE,
                     LEAD(T1.TIME,1) 
                         OVER (PARTITION BY T1.UNIT 
                               ORDER BY T1.UNIT, T1.TIME)
                         AS NEXT_RANGE
                     FROM table T1
                     WHERE T1.VALUE IS NOT NULL
                     ORDER BY T1.UNIT, T1.TIME
                ) T2
              ON (T1.TIME BETWEEN T2.TIME
                           AND COALESCE(NEXT_RANGE, CURRENT_DATE)) 
              AND T1.UNIT = T2.UNIT
```

Here is an SQLFiddle of the above query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d589b/1

Answer (score 9):

With some databases, e.g., Postgres, you can define your own aggregation functions.
LOCF is just a running COALESCE.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION locf_state( FLOAT, FLOAT )
RETURNS FLOAT
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $f$
  SELECT COALESCE($2,$1)
$f$;

CREATE AGGREGATE locf(FLOAT) (
  SFUNC = locf_state,
  STYPE = FLOAT
);
```

The query is then more readable:

```
SELECT unit, time, 
       locf(value) OVER( PARTITION BY unit ORDER BY time )
FROM   mytable;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2c73b/1/0

Comment: I have additional questions. How to 'CREATE AGGREGATE locf' on mssql